# upgrading to joomla 4 error jcontrollwer not found

Tags: joomla-4.x

I'm attempting to upgade my  joomla instillation to 4, but I have been having an error

An error has occurred.
0 Class "JController" not found

I don't know what to do?
Any help

Comment: Go to your Global Configuration and set the Debug to Yes and the Error Reporting to Maximum. This will provide more information regarding the message and where the failure is occurring. Also provide more information in your question explaining what you were doing like where in the processing of upgrading of Joomla you received the message.